# Error in load a 'rb' file using pickle in random forest algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, pickle, random-forest

```
import pickle
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report,accuracy_score,roc_auc_score

# print ('Number of arguments:', len(sys.argv), 'arguments.')
# print ('Argument List:', str(sys.argv))

with open('RF_Model_Py3', 'rb') as f:
    RanFor = pickle.load(f)
```

"

```
Exception has occurred: EOFError
Ran out of input
  File "C:\Users\HP\Downloads\Crop-Yield-Prediction-using-ML-master (1)\Crop-Yield-Prediction-using-ML-master\RF_predict.py", line 15, in <module>
    RanFor = pickle.load(f)
```

" this the error shown in vs code

After doing lots of steps the error doesn't clear. There is an error showing in the Randomforest algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The format for pickle.load is `pickle.load(open(filename,'rb'))`

In your case I would do `pickle.load(open('file.p','rb'))`

You should also make sure you have dumped the data before you try to load it